# Why does my Spring Boot application shuts down as soon as I run it?

Tags: spring-boot

I used Spring Initializr to set up my Spring Application. The application exits without any error as soon as I run it. The console logs this:

```
2021-02-22 13:31:20.206  INFO 68562 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-02-22 13:31:20.216  INFO 68562 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-02-22 13:31:20.294  INFO 68562 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

I tried changing the spring-boot-starter-parent version but that still doesn't seem to work. I tried rebuilding the project but that didn't work as well. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong here? It doesn't even return any error. It just doesn't run on the server.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.manjitmentor.sms</groupId>
    <artifactId>sms</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>sms</name>
    <description>Student Management System project by Java Full Stack Mentor Manjit Shakya.</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>logback-classic</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ch.qos.logback</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j-over-slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.9</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Logging-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here's my yml file:

```
server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    context-path: /sms
spring:
  application:
    name: sms
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SMS
    username: root
    password: idrunkh2o
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 100
      minimum-idel: 50
  jpa:
    database-platfrom: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

COMPLETE LOG:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=56405:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/aakashthakur-work/Documents/F1SoftManjitShakyaTraining/sms/target/classes:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.4.2/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.4.2/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.4.2.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.3.3/spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.6/aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.4.2/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.4.2.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/3.4.5/HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/5.3.3/spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/jakarta/transaction/jakarta.transaction-api/1.3.3/jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/jakarta/persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/2.4.3/spring-data-jpa-2.4.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.4.3/spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/5.3.3/spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.3.3/spring-context-5.3.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.3.3/spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.3.3/spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/5.3.3/spring-aspects-5.3.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.4.2/spring-boot-starter-web-2.4.2.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.4.2/spring-boot-starter-2.4.2.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.4.2/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.4.2.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.13.3/log4j-to-slf4j-2.13.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.13.3/log4j-api-2.13.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.30/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.30.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.27/snakeyaml-1.27.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.4.2/spring-boot-starter-json-2.4.2.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.11.4/jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.11.4/jackson-annotations-2.11.4.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.11.4/jackson-core-2.11.4.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.11.4/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.11.4.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.11.4/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.11.4.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.11.4/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.11.4.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.3.3/spring-web-5.3.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.3.3/spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.3.3/spring-expression-5.3.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/modelmapper/modelmapper/2.3.9/modelmapper-2.3.9.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-devtools/2.4.2/spring-boot-devtools-2.4.2.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.4.2/spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.4.2/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.22/mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.16/lombok-1.18.16.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.3/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.3/spring-core-5.3.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.3.3/spring-jcl-5.3.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.30/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.27.Final/hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.4.1.Final/jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/javax/persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.27.0-GA/javassist-3.27.0-GA.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.10.19/byte-buddy-1.10.19.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.1.1.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.1.3.Final/jandex-2.1.3.Final.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.5.1/classmate-1.5.1.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/dom4j/dom4j/2.1.3/dom4j-2.1.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.1.2.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.3/jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/2.3.3/txw2-2.3.3.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.11/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.11.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/com/sun/activation/jakarta.activation/1.2.2/jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar:/Users/aakashthakur-work/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.4.27.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-5.4.27.Final.jar com.manjitmentor.sms.SmsApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.2)

2021-02-22 15:03:29.750  INFO 74414 --- [  restartedMain] com.manjitmentor.sms.SmsApplication      : Starting SmsApplication using Java 11.0.9.1 on Aakashs-MacBook-Air.local with PID 74414 (/Users/aakashthakur-work/Documents/F1SoftManjitShakyaTraining/sms/target/classes started by aakashthakur-work in /Users/aakashthakur-work/Documents/F1SoftManjitShakyaTraining/sms)
2021-02-22 15:03:29.757  INFO 74414 --- [  restartedMain] com.manjitmentor.sms.SmsApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-02-22 15:03:29.949  INFO 74414 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-02-22 15:03:31.312  INFO 74414 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-02-22 15:03:31.431  INFO 74414 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 97 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-02-22 15:03:32.292  INFO 74414 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-02-22 15:03:32.448  INFO 74414 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.27.Final
2021-02-22 15:03:32.841  INFO 74414 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-02-22 15:03:33.179  INFO 74414 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-02-22 15:03:33.817  INFO 74414 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-02-22 15:03:33.930  INFO 74414 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2021-02-22 15:03:35.897  INFO 74414 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-02-22 15:03:35.922  INFO 74414 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-02-22 15:03:35.959  INFO 74414 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-02-22 15:03:36.963  INFO 74414 --- [  restartedMain] com.manjitmentor.sms.SmsApplication      : Started SmsApplication in 8.539 seconds (JVM running for 10.162)
2021-02-22 15:03:36.968  INFO 74414 --- [  restartedMain] com.manjitmentor.sms.SmsApplication      : 

,d88~~\      e    e      ,d88~~\ 
8888        d8b  d8b     8888    
`Y88b      d888bdY88b    `Y88b   
 `Y88b,   / Y88Y Y888b    `Y88b, 
   8888  /   YY   Y888b     8888 
\__88P' /          Y888b \__88P' 
                                 
2021-02-22 15:03:36.975  INFO 74414 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-02-22 15:03:36.982  INFO 74414 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-02-22 15:03:37.037  INFO 74414 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Provide complete trace log, please.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Just updated the question with complete log. Could you please help me out here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something is wrong with your Tomcat server. Maybe a conflict or something. Must check your `pom.xml`

Comment: Try starting your application with `--debug` as a command line argument. That will output the condition evaluation report which should show why Tomcat wasn't auto-configured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that this is causing trouble and you should remove it

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

You have this one that has the `Tomcat` already embedded

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

So a brief overview on why you faced the issue:

You tried to use an external tomcat and specified to your application that you will provide it to it by the runtime `<scope>provided</scope>` [check it here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html). But the application already has it embedded in it, and spring-boot by default creates a `jar` file, the `tomcat` needs a `war` file. In addition, the tomcat server won't launch your main method, you need to start your application as a normal spring app.

To use an external `tomcat` server follow these steps:

1. Set the packing to generate `war`

   `<packaging>war</packaging>`
2. Add the external `tomcat` dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupid>org.springframework.boot</groupid>
            <artifactid>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactid>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

3. Exclude the embedded tomcat from the `spring-boot-starter-web`

```
<dependency>
<groupid>org.springframework.boot</groupid>
<artifactid>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactid>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupid>org.springframework.boot</groupid>
                    <artifactid>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactid>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

And make a bunch of configurations to make it start as a `Spring app` and add the external configuration of your spring boot app on tomcat.

Check this article here I think it will complete the whole idea. [link](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-external-tomcat)

Comment: This solved my problem. The application runs on the server now. Could you tell me why adding another dependency which is already embedded caused this problem?

Comment: I updated my answer, I tried to give you a high overview of the whole thing. Hope it will help and check the link to understand the complete thing. Keep going. :)

Comment: Recently, I wanted to add slf4j&log4j dependencies to the Spring Boot application. And I had to exclude the logger from spring-boot-starter-web to make it work. Is this problem similar to that one? Because I saw you instructed to exclude embedded tomcat if I wanted to use my own dependency.

Comment: Yes if you want to use your own dependency then exclude the existing one from the Spring-boot dependencies. And this is almost legit for all the dependencies.

Comment: I have just started using Spring. I first used Servlet and JSPs with GlassFish server to understand how everything in web application works. Though Spring has made everything very easy and neat, the internal working of Spring is harder for me to understand. How would you suggest me to go about it given your understandings.

Comment: Of course `Spring` and especially `SpringBoot` have well-defined implementations of the general specifications. Actually, `SpringBoot` does everything for you. I believe that `Java EE` is old enough, ok I know the `Jakarta EE` gave a fresh air but in comparison with Spring which provides you a whole eco-System is still old. I suggest you be up to date and use the latest technologies. They help you build great software, flexible and very secure. I am still a junior software engineer and those are tips that an architect gave me from my previous job. So I suggest you do the same.

Comment: About the understanding of `Spring`: it is a huge framework to master. Slow steps at a time. Read from others, try to understand the concepts `containers` `IOC`, `dependency injection` and this stuff. As you grow on understanding you will follow more advanced stuff. Keep going :)

Comment: Liked the way you say 'Keep Going'. I'm on my first baby steps to master Spring. No matter how many new concepts I try to understand, there is always more.

Comment: This is software engineering bud :) There will always be more.